# Testing Specific Method Calls with Parameters using Moq

Tags: moq

I'm trying to write a Unit Test with Moq to verify that a Registration was successful. My Test is as follows:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void RegisterTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var MockRepo = new Mock<IDataRepo>() ;             
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
        {
            ConfirmPassword = "SamePassword",
            Email = "myemail@address.com",
            FirstName = "MyFirstName",
            LastName = "MyLastName",
            MiddleName = "MyMiddleName",
            Password = "SamePassword"
        };
        MockRepo.Setup(ctx => ctx.Add(model)).Verifiable("Nothing was added to the Database");

        //Act
        AccountController target = new AccountController(MockRepo.Object);

        //Assert
        ActionResult actual = target.Register(model);
        MockRepo.Verify(ctx => ctx.Add(It.IsAny<RegisterModel>()));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
    }
```

But it fails with the following Error

```
 Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: ctx => ctx.Add(It.IsAny())
```

However, When I debugged the Test Method, I noticed that the Add(T) method was actually called.
The MOQ dll version is v4.0

**UPDATE**
Account Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private IDataRepo _repo;

    public AccountController(IDataRepo Repo)
    {
        _repo = Repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = _repo.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user == null)
            {
                _repo.Add(new User
                {
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Password = model.Password,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    MiddleName = model.MiddleName
                });

                return View("RegistrationSuccess");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("UserExists", "This Email already Exists");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your the `Register` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your Mock expects a `RegisterModel` instance

```
RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
{
    ConfirmPassword = "SamePassword",
    Email = "myemail@address.com",
    FirstName = "MyFirstName",
    LastName = "MyLastName",
    MiddleName = "MyMiddleName",
    Password = "SamePassword"
};

MockRepo.Setup(ctx => ctx.Add(model))
```

but the `Add` method gets called with an instance of the `User` class

```
_repo.Add(new User
{
    Email = model.Email,
    Password = model.Password,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
    MiddleName = model.MiddleName
});
```

---

So, one way to get around this is to setup the mock to accept a `User` instance.

```
RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
{
    ConfirmPassword = "SamePassword",
    Email = "myemail@address.com",
    FirstName = "MyFirstName",
    LastName = "MyLastName",
    MiddleName = "MyMiddleName",
    Password = "SamePassword"
};
User expected = new User
{
    Email = model.Email,
    Password = model.Password,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
    MiddleName = model.MiddleName
};
MockRepo.Setup(ctx => ctx.Add(expected))
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an easier way to do it. Rather than generate your own User object you could call `It.IsAny<User>()` and the test would run just fine. so my unit test now becomes..

```
        //Arrange
        var MockRepo = new Mock<IDataRepo>() ;             
        var MockMembership = new Mock<IMembership>();
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
        {
            ConfirmPassword = "SamePassword",
            Email = "myemail@address.com",
            FirstName = "MyFirstName",
            LastName = "MyLastName",
            MiddleName = "MyMiddleName",
            Password = "SamePassword"
        };

        MockRepo.Setup(ctx => ctx.Add(It.IsAny<User>())).Verifiable("Nothing was added to the Database");
        //Act
        AccountController target = new AccountController(MockRepo.Object, MockMembership.Object);

        //Assert
        ActionResult actual = target.Register(model);
        MockRepo.Verify(ctx => ctx.Add(It.IsAny<User>()));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
```

Comment: Note that now your test is less specific, since you now just test for *any* user instance, not one that has the right properties. So your test would not fail if the `AccountController` class would call `_repo.Add(new User());` instead of `_repo.Add(new User() { ... set properties right ... })`.